# Ajax Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: ajax

Hi i have a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } " error on 137 line of my code

```
function removeItem(sender, itemCode){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart_update.php?removep=' + itemCode,
        success: function(){
            var parent = $(sender).parent();
            parent.remove();
            });
        } ////137
}
```

Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to close the $.ajax leading parenthesis:

```
      }); ////137
}
```

Just add a ");" on line 137

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing `);` on line marked with `////137`

And you have unneeded `);` on line above the `////137`

Correct code

```
function removeItem(sender, itemCode){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart_update.php?removep=' + itemCode,
        success: function(){
            var parent = $(sender).parent();
            parent.remove();
        }
    }); ////137
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
function removeItem(sender, itemCode){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart_update.php?removep=' + itemCode,
        success: function(){
            var parent = $(sender).parent();
            parent.remove();
            });
        });
}
```

You missed the closings for $.ajax();